# Eigen: speed up complex matrix inversion

Tags: c++, matrix, arm, eigen, neon

I am developing embedded software on Zynq MPSOC Cortex-A53 (Armv7/Armv8) for image processing, and I need some help for developing a specific algorithm.

The algorithm involves inversion of complex matrix, with large dimension up to 30x30. (By complex matrix, I mean complex float number with real and imaginary parts).

The most significant constraint is obviously the **timing constraint**: we use to develop our algorithms with ARM NEON SIMD to be faster.

To do it, I am currently testing **Eigen v3.3.5** library.
I wrote the code to do the inversion and, for a matrix 24x24 (type complex double, function **Eigen::MatrixXcd::inverse()**): I got an average duration of **10,5 ms**.

My code:

```
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

static const unsigned int N_ROWS = 24;
static const unsigned int N_COLS = 24;
static const unsigned int NB_test = 20U;

// MAIN
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  TimeTools TheTimer;
  Eigen::MatrixXcd Matrix_cpx(N_ROWS, N_COLS);
  Eigen::MatrixXcd Matrix_cpx_inv;

  F32 ChronoResult[NB_test] = {0.0};
  for(unsigned int TestIdx = 0U; TestIdx < NB_test; TestIdx ++)
  {
    // Get random matrix
    Matrix_cpx = Eigen::MatrixXcd::Random(N_ROWS, N_COLS);

    TheTimer.StartChrono();
    // Inverse matrix
    Matrix_cpx_inv = Matrix_cpx.inverse();
    TheTimer.StopChrono();

    // Save chrono
    ChronoResult[TestIdx] = TheTimer.GetChronoValue();
  }

  std::cout << "\nM matrix is:\n" << Matrix_cpx << std::endl;
  std::cout << "\nM_inv matrix is:\n" << Matrix_cpx_inv << std::endl;
  F64 SumChrono = 0.0;
  for(unsigned int TestIdx = 0U; TestIdx < NB_test; TestIdx ++)
  {
    std::cout << "\nMatrix_Inversion duration[" << TestIdx << "] = "<< ChronoResult[TestIdx] << " ms" << std::endl;
    SumChrono += ChronoResult[TestIdx];
  }
  std::cout << "\nMatrix_Inversion average duration = "<< (SumChrono / NB_test) << " ms" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Note: behind TimeTools, *gettimeofday()* is used.

My goal is to speed up this matrix inversion.
Consequenlty, I need your help: **how to make it go faster?**

I know that Eigen may use the ARM NEON SIMD to optimize certain functions, but I am not sure that Eigen does use it for the matrix inversion. How to know that?

**Do I need to set an option (= define) to enable NEON? Or, other options which can optimize Eigen code?**

Notes:

- Compiler *arm-linux-gnueabi-g++* (32bits)
- Compiler options: *-mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-vfpv4*
- Processor runs at 1,2 GHz.

Thanking you in advance.

Regards,

Laurent.

**UPDATE**

I forgot the optimizations flag... With `-O3` compiler option, I got a **0,82 ms** duration.

Any ideas to optimize more will be welcome!

**UPDATE2**

With `ffast-math` build option, I got round **0,4 ms** duration.

I keep looking for a faster implementation!

Comment: Less speeding up an algorithm, more "are there any Eigen settings to make it go faster?

Comment: Could you be more specific about "algorithm" and add some sample?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you use Eigen's `inverse()`? Also, are you sure you really need to compute the inverse explicitly? If you're only using it to apply it to some vectors or matrices, it might be faster to keep it in factored form. One more: is your matrix hermitian?

Comment: I think you need `-mfloat-abi=hard` for better performance.

Comment: 10ms for a 24x24 matrix of `complex<double>` seems to be super slow. On a x86 with SSE, 2.6GHz, I got 0.054ms for `Eigen::Matrix::inverse()`. Don't forget `-O3 -DNDEBUG` when benchmarking.

Comment: @ggael `-mfloat-abi=hard` is obsolete on `Aarch64`, and even on `Aarch32`, it won't bring much - if at all since it only affects parameter passing compared to the `softfp` option. And the whole project needs to be built by the `hf` version of toolchain which is out of question most of the time. Android NDK is bound to `softfp` version for example.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it a bit quickly yesterday!
I made some update, with the code, etc...

AND... I forgot the optimizations! With the `-O3`, it definitely works better!
I got an average duration of **0,8 ms**.

Our processor runs at around 1 GHz.
Thanks all.

Comment: If you have any other ideas to optimize more, do not hesitate to post it.
Thanks!

Comment: maybe you're allowed to use [-ffast-math](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) ?

Comment: Hi @MikevanDyke, thanks for your idea!
I did try the `-ffast-math` build option, and it improves my timing results with complex numbers (not ones with real matrix): I got **0,4 ms**.
I have no idea of the inconvenient using -ffast-math option.

But this is still not enough :-). My goal is to get around 0,05 ms... 
Thanks!

Comment: Using a 64-bit compiler (mb check out the linaro toolchain) would help as well, but it most certainly will not reduce runtime to 0.05ms.

Comment: Yes, I did try also the `arm-aarch64-linux` compiler (Armv8) but I got same timing as the 32bits one with ffast-math option (eg. 0.4 ms).
Besides, I did test the ArmPL library but not better as Eigen, same results.
I cannot change my toolchain to linaro, sorry.
Keep hoping!

Comment: Is your matrix an arbitrary matrix? Or does it have any structure, like symmetric or PSD?